# Disassembling IKEA Ingolf chair

Tags: joints, removal, self-assembly-furniture

I have a couple of dining room chairs from IKEA, which have been quite good for a number of years.

One of them, however, has started wobbling a bit, and I saw that it was because the back of the chair is no more strongly fixed to the frame.

I am trying to disassemble it, but the latch/joint that is used, I can't understand, how should I remove it.

As you can see in the image, it is 2 metal parts, which slide and probably click into each other (it was ages ago when I assembled it, so I don't remember):

[image: IKEA Ingolf assembly]

They are fixed firmly and are not moving in any direction. There is a small slit between the parts, when viewed from below:
[image: latch]

However, I can only put in a very short length of screwdriver  inside, there doesn't feel anything much there and I am concerned I might break the screwdriver if I pushed harder.

Any ideas how to dismantle this?

Comment: Hard to tell, but try rotating the tip of the leg slightly toward the "hinge" on the clip. It appears rotating as such, then pulling could relieve the locking mechanism. Also, FWIW, IKEA is generally not manufactured with disassembly in mind, so it's possible you're undoing a fastener that wasn't meant to be undone.

Comment: They might be wedges that tighten when weight is applied to the seat. I would try hitting the apron (horizontal member) from the underside using a large wooden mallet (or use a hammer with a sacrificial piece of wood to protect the apron).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will tap/slide apart. if it's stiff (as mine were) then a place a slotted screwdriver on the metal bracket on the left hand side in the photograph and give it a tab using a hammer. This will help to avoid stressing the 3 screws used to hold this part of the fixing into the wood.

Answer (score 1):

THey don't click together permanently.  Just tap them apart in a manner that is the reverse of image 1 in the diagram